# How to select 3 characters from string to the left of specific part of string in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, parsing

I have a column in SQL that I am trying to parse out with data that looks like this:

```
ID             
Big Red Truck   
Small Green Truck - 12pk           
Orange Truck - 3pk              
Small Blue Truck
```

If the string contains 'pk' I want to select 3 characters to the left otherwise return null or blank. I'd like the output to look something like this:

```
ID             
NULL  
 12           
 3             
NULL
```

Comment: hint : pls use SUBSTR, INSTR to locate and extract

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to do exactly as you asked and return the prior 3 chars.  I add the other just in case you want just the number.  If you need to do more than this, then I would take advantage of the CTE and do it in steps rather than a left+charindex to remove the pk and beyond and a reverse+left+charindex to remove the "-" and before.

```
with test as (
    select * 
    from(
        values ('ID'),('Big Red Truck'),('Small Green Truck - 12pk'),('Orange Truck - 3pk'),('Small Blue Truck')
        ) t(value)
) 
select value, 
    charindex('pk', value) as [pk_index], 
    substring(value, charindex('pk', value) - 3, 3) as [prior_3],
    trim(replace(substring(value, charindex('pk', value) - 3, 3), '-', '')) as [prior_3_trim]
from test
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case, "pk" appears at the end of the string:

```
select (case when id like '%pk'
             then left(right(str, 5), 3)
        end)
```